# missing cryptsetup-reencrypt command in packages

Tags: package-management, cryptsetup

I'm encrypting my home partition in laptop. I need to exec "cryptsetup-reencrypt /dev/sda5 --new --reduce-device-size 16M --type=luks1" but system says that the command isn't installed and I must use "sudo apt install cryptsetup-bin" to install it.
I tried "sudo apt install cryptsetup-bin" and "sudo apt install --reinstall cryptsetup-bin" but the "cryptsetup-reencrypt" command is missing at all.
My question is if there are some equivalent command in a new package or perhaps the problem is an error in the package?